# MySQL SSL using MariaDB JDBC Driver

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds, jdbc, ssl

We have the following setup:

Ec2 instance running a jboss server with mariadb (1.1.7) datasources setup to connect to an rds instance running MySQL 5.6.21.

We would like to turn on SSL on for this connection so took the following steps:

Add `require ssl` to the MySQL users. 
Verify that this has worked by first running:

```
mysql -h HOSTNAME -u USER -pPASS
```

and getting the expected

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User'@'10.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

then trying

```
mysql -h HOSTNAME -u USER -pPASS --ssl_ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

this connects no problems.

So, great, it appears that ssl has been setup just fine. Now time to modify the -ds.xml files that define our application's connection.

From searching I found that you must add `?useSSL=true;` to the end of the url defined in your datasource.

We tried running this and got access denied when the server tried to open those connections. Thinking it was because we had not specified the key, we then added that to the java `cacerts` file. No change. So instead we tried to add `?useSSL=true;serverSslCert=/tmp/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem;` still no change, getting a stack trace on connection.

```
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'User'@'10.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried various other url parameters and certificate stores but still no change. Can anybody suggest anything?

Cheers

Comment: Just to add - the biggest issue in debugging this has been the useless 'access denied' error message. I understand why generic messages are good for security but I haven't been able to find anyway to get a real reason through SQL logs that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I cannot find into [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) any reference to `serverSslCert` parameter. However the parameter are separated by `&` and not by `;` char.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment - serverSslCert is a mariadb parameter - see here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-the-mariadb-java-client/

Comment: Also worth noting that unless anybody can prove us wrong we believe we have narrowed it down to some bug in JBoss, writing a standalone application to use the same mariadb driver and same datasource worked just fine.